# Is O(1) access to a database row is possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-design, optimization

I have an table which use an auto-increment field (ID) as primary key. The table is append only and no row will be deleted. Table has been designed to have a constant row size.

Hence, I expected to have O(1) access time using any value as ID since it is easy to compute exact position to seek in file (ID*row_size), unfortunately that is not the case.

I'm using SQL Server.
Is it even possible ?

Thanks

Comment: The only time you approach O(1) is with a hash.

Comment: @KevinDTimm -- or if the table only has one row. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the thing that matters to you is the performance.
Databases use indexes to access records which are written on the disk.

Usually this is done with B+ tree indexes, which are log<sub>b</sub>n where b for internal nodes is typically between 100 and 200 (optimized to block size, see [ref](http://www.cecs.csulb.edu/~monge/classes/share/B+TreeIndexes.html))

This is still strictly speaking logarithmic performance, but given decent number of records, let's say a few million, the leaf nodes can be reached in 3 to 4 steps and that, together with all the overhead for query planning, session initiation, locking, etc (that you would have anyway if you need multiuser, ACID compliant data management system) is certainly for all practical reasons comparable to constant time.

Answer (score 3):

> Hence, I expected to have O(1) access
>   time using any value as ID since it is
>   easy to compute exact position to seek
>   in file (ID*row_size),

Ah. No. Autoincrement does not - even without deletions -guarantee no holes. Holes = seek via index. Ergo: your assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that an indexed read is O(log(n)) which for large values of n gets pretty close to O(1). That said in this context O notation is not very useful, and actual timings are far more meanigful.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it were possible to address rows directly, your query would still have to go through the client and server protocol stacks and carry out various lookups and memory allocations before it could give the result you want. It seems like you are expecting something that isn't even practical. What is the real problem here? Is SQL Server not fast enough for you? If so there are many options you can use to improve performance but directly seeking an address in a file is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. SQL Server organizes data into a tree-like structure based on key and index values; an "index" in the DB sense is more like a reference book's index and not like an indexed data structure like an array or list. At best, you can get logarithmic performance when searching on an indexed value (PKs are generally treated as an index). Worst-case is a table scan for a non-indexed column, which is linear. Until the database gets very large, the seek time of a well-designed query against a well-designed table will pale in comparison to the time required to send it over the network or even a named pipe.